# Performatic insert into database to catch duplicate key error

Tags: java, mysql, database, insert, primary-key

My application can occur to insert duplicate primary key data, my doubt is what would be the most performative way, check before inserting if the key already exists or simply insert and let the bank return an error and then treat it? Which has less impact?
I thank

Comment: _let the bank return an error_  So do we assume you are calling someone elses code here rather than maintaining your own database?

Comment: Or do you mean _let the database return an error_?

Comment: How often does this happen

Comment: The application is my own, and the number of times this can happen will not be great, my doubt is more didactic, I would like to know if in terms of performance it is better for me to check before performing a find or simply send the data and capture the error of duplicate bank key?

Comment: If it will not happen often I would go for the second option, let the DB report the dup error and act appropriately when that happens

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most performant method would be to use an `INSERT` query with a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.

This will insert a new record if the primary key doesn't exist and will update only the specified fields for the primary key record if it already exists (it will not throw an error).

For example the following code will create a new user if the the `user_id` doesn't exist.  If the `user_id` does exist, it will only update the `last_visited_date`.

```
INSERT INTO users
    (user_id, last_visited_date)
VALUES
    ({user_id}, UTC_TIMESTAMP())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    last_visited_date= VALUES(last_visited_date)
```

This approach allows you to both create new records and update already existing records with one query, which prevents the need for checking for an already existing primary key.

Note: if the primary key is an auto-incremented index, MySQL treats `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` clauses the same as `INSERT` queries so the next ID will be incremented by `1` anytime the primary key already exists.

If you don't want to use an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, catching the error for already existing primary keys would be the most performant.